# Angular Service Definition: service or factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am an angular newbie, I am building an application, one thing really puzzling me is there are couple of ways of defining a service, and I read more from this link: [How to define service](http://iffycan.blogspot.com/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html)
then it seems there is no big difference among the ways of defining a service.

but I just noticed one difference which I think is different:

see this service I get from here http://jsfiddle.net/2by3X/5/

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('test', function($timeout, $q) {
  var self = this;
  this.getSomething = function() {
    return self.getData().then(function(data) {
      return self.compactData(data);
    });
  };
  this.getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve("foo");
      }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  this.compactData = function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    console.log(data);

    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("bar");
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
  };
});
```

if I define this service using "factory" like below, one function cannot call other functions of the service.

```js
app.factory('test', function($timeout, $q) {
  return {
      getSomething : function() {
    return getData().then(function(data) {
      return compactData(data);
    });
  },

      getData : function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve("foo");
      }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
  },

      compactData : function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    console.log(data);

    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("bar");
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
  },
 };
});
```

I will get this in the browser console:

```
[08:41:13.701] "Error: getData is not defined
.getSomething@http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:47
Ctrl1@http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:75
invoke@http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2795
instantiate@http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js:2805
```

Can anyone explain this? thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you  have two big problems there:

- the factory returns an object with incorrect syntax.
- javascript scope of variables is functional

That is,
You should be returning an object like `{key: value, key: value}`

values can be functions. however, you return `{key = value, key = value}`

First fix:

```js
return { 
    getSomething : function() {...},
    getData : function... 
}
```

Secondly, not being able to call functions is normal. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MVt/4/). I mocked everything. You can call one of the functions returned by the service. However, when from getSomething try to call getData, you get "undefined":

```js
app.factory('testSO', function () {
return {
    getSomething: function () {
        console.log('return getsomething');
        getData();
    },

    getData: function () {
        console.log('return getData');
    }...
```

This would be the same as declaring everything in the scope of the factory function  and return references [see in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MVt/5/):

```js
app.factory('testSO', function () {
    var getSomething = function () {
        console.log('return getsomething');
    };
    ...
return {
    getSomething: getSomething,
    ...
}
```

and now you can call local functions as shown in the [final version of the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MVt/6/):

```js
app.factory('testSO', function () {
    var getSomething = function () {
        console.log('return getsomething');
        getData();
    };
...
```

The original service has something important in it: `var self = this;` . Some people use  [var that = this](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations). It's a workaround for an error in ECMA.
In the case of the original code, it's used to "put everything in one object". Functions (properties that happen to be functions) in  `self` need a reference to know where the function you want to call is.  Try it yourself here http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MVt/7/

Comment: no prob :) I updated the answer to add a quick explanation of the this-that thing in the original code. See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MVt/7/

Comment: +1, nice use of the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)