# Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined Highcharts-ng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Have a problem in highcharts-ng,

First of all, please look at this demo

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jwtY21JoQsEq40nP4Tf?p=preview)

In this demo, if you see, I have two buttons on the top,

```
<input type='button' value='change to map' ng-click='showMap("region")' />
    <input type='button' value='change to bar' ng-click='showMap("sites")' />
```

On click on the button, I am generating different maps,

But I am getting the error also in the console like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined
    at Object.Ya.destroy (http://code.highcharts.com/3.0/highcharts.js:207:141)
```

Please help me in this

Comment: Have you tried to check if without angular and highcharts-ng it works properly or not?

Comment: With out angular and highcharts-ng, it will work. But my need is to work with highcharts-ng and angular

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I want to know one thing, can we draw the Map chart using new Highcharts.charts('Maps', <options>) ?

Comment: Generally, or in highcharts-ng?

Comment: asking in General highcharts.js, basically the highcharts-ng.js uses the same way as highcharts.js like new Highcharts.Chart(mergedOptions, func); were mergedOptions are options, and func is the call back function

Comment: I know, in the highcharts you need to use Highcharts.Map(options);
http://jsfiddle.net/2s26Q/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feeding the data through an angular factory to a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697542/feeding-the-data-through-an-angular-factory-to-a-controller)