# Calling a 'sibling' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some code that looks like this

```
var viewService = function () {
   ...
   return {
      ...
      ,isAbsolute: function (view) { ... }
      ...
      ,removeAbsoluteViews: function () { ... }
      }
   };
};
```

What I'd like to do is call `isAbsolute` from `removeAbsoluteViews`.  When I try to do that like this

```
if (isAbsolute(v) === false) { ... }
```

I get an error saying `isAbsolute` is not defined.  How can I do this?

Comment: Define the scope by `this`.

Comment: tried that - didn't work.

Comment: if `if (this.isAbsolute(v) === false)` didn't work, it would be because `removeAbsoluteViews` didn't have the correctly scoped `this`. You should also indicate how you're calling `removeAbsoluteViews`. The following example shows how `this` scoping can fail:
`setTimeout(viewService.removeAbsoluteViews, 50);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Since you return an object you can use the `this` keyword:

```
if (this.isAbsolute(v) === false) { ... }
```

#### You can also declare it like so (without the `this` keyword):

```
var viewService = function () {

  function isAbsolute (view) { ... }

  function removeAbsoluteViews () { 
    if (isAbsolute(v) === false) { ... }
  }

  ...

  return {
    isAbsolute: isAbsolute,
    removeAbsoluteViews: removeAbsoluteViews
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

With a [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

[Angular Service Definition: service or factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449383/angular-service-defination-service-or-factory/17450047#17450047)