# which use Angularjs Factory vs Service

Tags: angularjs

I am reading Angularjs documentation, and I see Factory and Service types are very similar. I am new at angularjs and I cuold not understand which I should use in real projects. Which problem can solved by Factory or Service.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449383/angular-service-defination-service-or-factory/17450047#17450047

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)

Comment: Factory vs. Service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory/24442224#24442224